# Jquery Datepicker not displayed on first click

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using JQueryUI datepicker, when clicking on the calendar image for the first time the calendar is not shown. However, when a postback occurs then the calender is displayed.

I am using the below is the code snippet to initialize datepicker:

```js
$(function() {
      var date = new Date();
      var currentMonth = date.getMonth();
      var currentDate = date.getDate();
      var currentYear = date.getFullYear();

      $("#ReportDate").datepicker({
        showOn: "both",
        buttonImage: "calendar.png",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        buttonText: "Select date",
        maxDate: new Date(currentYear, currentMonth, currentDate)
      });
   });
```

```css
  .ui-datepicker {
            font-size: 8pt !important;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>jQuery UI Datepicker</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div class="demo">
<b>Date:</b> <input type="text" id="ReportDate" />
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Can any one please help. I am really stuck from long time.**

Comment: could you post a fiddle for the same

Comment: Code, filddle or plunker. Provide something

Comment: are u informing us or asking ? please post your codes and problem

Comment: The code fiddle you have provided doesn't work! Make sure to `Run` the code before you *fishing* post it for the others! Moreover, the code you have posted is syntactically wrong!

Comment: Your code fiddle doesn't work! Check!

Answer (score 0):

Are you initializing your datepicker on pageload?

```html
<script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
</script>
```

**EDIT**

Probably the references are wrong.
Try this: https://jsfiddle.net/ddan/8vjtzru4/1/

Comment: @Vineeta I tried many of the stuff still its not working. I think the click event is not getting attahed firt time whn the page is loaded. I couldn't attach the image else it would  have been clear to make  you guys understand :(

Comment: No its still the same issue. I replaced my Jquery and CSS references with the one you provided. Also. My testbox is ASp.net textbox: 
<asp:TextBox ID="ReportDate" runat="server" />

Comment: That's interesting. In the JSFiddle it works.
Did you replace the JS code. In your example it is missing from the end a  '});'

Comment: Yours won't run because of wrong syntax, the function is not closed.

Comment: It was a typo while pasting into the fiddle. I am have valid syntax in my code @DDan

Comment: Probably you have a different issue then. Perhaps asp.net problem.
Your javascript problem is solved based on your question.

Comment: It works well after the post back. But doesn't work on first load. I am not sure what happens after the post back and it stats working. I think some how the datepicker is not getting initialized before postback and also there is not click event attached. When I click on textbox or image nothing happens even after binding them to click event.                              `$('#ReportDate').on("click", function(){ console.log("click event");});` @ddan

Answer (score 0):

As pe rmy understanding, This problem usually occurs when the input field is the first input of the page and is already focused state when dom initializes.So we need to click the field once more to initialize focus and datepicker. so better initialize datepicker on click function.

```
$('#datepicker').click(function(){
    $('#datepicker').datepicker('show');
});
```

offcouse fiddle or plunker demo of question will help more with answers.

Comment: Even I tried that but it doesn't works until unless postback happens on the page.

Answer (score 0):

I think mistake in your script tag

i have update your code [Here](http://codebeautify.org/htmlviewer/c144d2)

check this link and let me know it's working or not.

Comment: Even then its not working on my page. It seems to be working fine If I place it on html page. But not working on .aspx page when it has to do something with postback.